# PHP failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! 503 error

Tags: php, web-scraping, file-get-contents

I am using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to get a data from a website. I call this following function in  a while loop say for example 15 actors data to be scraped. what happens is after scraping data for 5 or 6 or somewhere in loop, it fails to open the stream and  breaks the script. I used try and catch function. but still i am not to fix it out. Actually my need is even if it fails in the middle of a loop, it has to go on till the end. Can anyone assit me pls.

```
    function get_data($actor)  {
        try { 

            $html = file_get_html('http://someurl.com', false, $context);

            if (isset($html)) { 

            $table1 =$html->find('table.table_border',0) ; 
                 // doing some process here
            }

        } catch(Exception $e) {
         echo $tt_id."-Failed once.<br>";
        }

    }
```

Sometimes i am getting the following error and the script stops.

```
        Warning: file_get_contents(http://someurl.com) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable 

        Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in somefile.php on line 37
```

Comment: do you have a live sample url that we can look at?

Comment: Indra, Try to check the url which you are trying to get, I feel issue is on there side or site is not responding.

Comment: sorry sir I cannot reveal the URL.

Comment: @RamSharma Yes you are right. Its heavy traffic website. But what i want is to catch the error if it fails to go on.

Comment: than use `if($html != FALSE)`

Comment: Probably better to use: `if ($html !== FALSE) {`

Comment: @RamSharma and kiko ---  if ($html !== FALSE) {  -- It works. Thanks both of you